# font-family rule is ignored

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm in the process of updating a site for someone, and I'm trying to get rid of a global `@font-face` and apply it only to specific elements.

It was defined like this:

```
@font-face {  
    font-family: "neutra";  
    src: url( /styles/NeutraDisp-Bold.eot ); /* IE */  
    src: local("Neutra Display"), url( /styles/NeutraDisp-Bold.ttf ) format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}

@font-face {  
    font-family: "futura";  
    src: url( /styles/FuturaStd-Heavy.eot ); /* IE */  
    src: local("Futura Std"), url( /styles/FuturaStd-Heavy.ttf ) format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-family: neutra, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

I only want it on a div that has the class `.header` and `legend`s (and a few other tags, eventually) so I modified the CSS to look like this instead:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}


@font-face {  
    font-family: "neutra";  
    src: url('../../styles/NeutraDisp-Bold.eot'); /* IE */  
    src: local("Neutra Display"), url('../../styles/NeutraDisp-Bold.ttf') format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}

@font-face {  
    font-family: "futura";  
    src: url('../../styles/FuturaStd-Heavy.eot'); /* IE */  
    src: local("Futura Std"), url('../../styles/FuturaStd-Heavy.ttf') format("truetype"); /* non-IE */  
}

legend{
    font-family: neutra, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .125em;

    -webkit-border-radius: .5em;
    -moz-border-radius: .5em;
    border-radius: .5em;
}

.header{
    width: 75em;
    height: 12.375em;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: neutra, Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

However, the `.header` `font-family` is being ignored.  All of the other declarations in that rule are used, and Firebug shows the `font-family`, which indicates to me that it's valid CSS.

In addition, the `legend` rule works perfectly, and shows the correct font.

Note: I moved the fonts and various other things around when I started working, but I know the new font paths are correct, because the `legend` rule works.  I've also tried `"neutra"` and `'neutra'`.

A [pastebin of the **entire** CSS is here](http://pastebin.com/SjZQxgWR), if you think the problem is somewhere else.  I've also created [a jsfiddle with a fontface included](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/gWTgP/) to see an example of it being ignored.

**Old Update**
The jsfiddle is doing what it should.  I have no idea what is different in my own code.

### Update

I've added the offending rule.  I think I'm missing something about rule weights, which would be why a lower rule still isn't overriding a higher one.

Comment: Can you post the html where .header is being used ? or if possible, setup a fiddle on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: is there a chance you're trying to put the header element in an element that is not acceptable... For instance, I dummied myself w/ this earlier today... I was trying to render <p><span style="somestuff"></span></p> and it would not render the css in the span because spans get "tempermental" when put inside p tags... Could it be the way header is nested?

Comment: @Russ C: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/gWTgP/).  Note the managed resources.

Comment: the font face is set on just about every element directly, `.header` is being beaten out by rules on nested `div`, `p`, etc.

Comment: @numbers1311407 are you saying that you have to explicitly define the `font-family` for each element, even if it's parent has it defined?

Comment: no, it'd be better to just define it somewhere near the top, like on `html`, then your override on `.header` would take precedence.  I.e. instead of that long list of elements, simply `html { font-face: whatev; }`

Comment: @numbers1311407 I was under the impression that's what was happening.  I defined `html` to have `arial, Helvetica` etc., and then I defined `.header` to have `neutra`.  I'm really confused.

Comment: you defined `html` to have arial, along with applying it directly to most other elements directly.  You could cut that whole rule back to simply `html` or `body`, which would apply to all children unless overridden (e.g. by `.header`).  I made an answer below which expands on this a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's an issue of precedence.  Check it out at w3:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

Your first rule which sets the default as Arial also directly applies the font-face to most html elements.  This is unnecessary and causing your problem.  Rather you should just set it once, on a top level element like `html`.

```
/* this single rule applies the Arial font to the whole document tree under <html> */
html { font-face: Arial, etc; }

/* this would set the font on .header, and everything inside of it */
.header { font-face: neutra, etc; }
```

In your case, `p { font-face: Arial; }` and `div { font-face: Arial; }` and etc beat your your singly nested `.header` rule.  If you cut that long rule back to just a top level element, it will solve your problem.

Small example of the css cascade here, with the original long rule declaration:

```
<html>
  <body>
    My text is Arial because I exist under html and there are 
    no other rules modifying me.

    <div class="header">
      My text is neutra because I'm a direct child text node of "header"

      <p>
         my text is Arial because of the rule on "p", which in turn overrides
         the rule on "header"
      </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The long rule is a reset, but I've removed the font-family declaration and added it to it's own rule- on `html` only.  This fixed my problems.  Thanks for your explanation of why this is happening.

Comment: To be sure your reset continues to work as expected you may want to replace the rule `font: inherit`, which is typical to resets.

Comment: It's not an issue of specificity, but one of inheritance.

Comment: Edited to precedence.  I had been under the impression that inheritance was part of specificity calculation.

Answer (score 3):

For a quick check, have you tried :

```
.header, .header *{
    font-family: neutra, Helvetica, Arial, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
```

Since you're specifying a font-family for a lot of the tags, maybe that first set-up is too "strong".

Comment: I added `.header *{}` with the `font-family` declaration, and it worked.    Why wasn't the rule being inherited by the children of `.header` automatically?  Is there something about font-family inheritance that's not being made clear here?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you are using the html5 `<header>` element and defining the style for the element in your css as `.header {}` (a class) instead of `header {}`?

Comment: Nope, just a `<div class="header">` :(